# how to understand NetworkInterface and InetAddress concept?

Tags: java, network-programming

I think in java, NetworkInterface is abstraction of network card . If this is right , why one `NetworkInterface` contains more than one `InetAddress` ?

for example this code in my macbook :

```
NetworkInterface en0 = NetworkInterface.getByName("en0");
Enumeration<InetAddress> adrs = en0.getInetAddresses() ;
while(adrs.hasMoreElements()){
    InetAddress adr = adrs.nextElement();
    System.out.println(adr.getHostAddress());
}
```

Output:

```
fe80:0:0:0:7a31:c1ff:feb7:a3a2%4
192.168.1.100
```

There are two address, but I didn't use IPv6.

My question is that, how to understand this two concepts? What's their relationship?

Answer (score 0):

> why one NetworkInterface contains more than one InetAddress?

Because you can configure an NIC with multiple addresses. This has been the case for about twenty years.

> I didn't use IPv6

Somebody did. Maybe you're using DHCP and it came from there.